# Installing h5py on Windows fails - Possibly a 32 vs 64bit issue?

Tags: python, python-2.7, h5py

I just switched my python installation to the lovely Anaconda and am trying to get the packages I use often installed and working again.  Unfortunately I'm having some problems getting h5py to work - the Python 2.7 installer available from h5py.org seems not to work.  After the first screen, an error message pops up saying that Python Version 2.7 is required but was not found in the registry.  Python 2.7 is the only version I have on this computer (specifically 2.7.5, Anaconda 1.8.0 (64-bit)).  Has anyone else experienced this issue?  Some people in a long-forgotten thread were worried it could be a 32 vs 64-bit python issue, but nothing ever came out of that.  Any ideas / will I also need a 32-bit python installation for this to work?

Comment: did you read the note on the download page about 64-bit builds being available on a 3rd party website? http://www.h5py.org/dl/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download 64-bit h5py from here and try again
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#h5py

(as recommended by http://www.h5py.org/dl/)

Comment: Ugh, thanks.  Didn't see that link since there were also downloads on the home page.